# Guice - Injecting different value to string variable per instance

Tags: binding, guice, multiple-instances, code-injection

Using Guice,I would like create three different instances for my Color class i.e BLUE, RED, YELLOW and want to bind different color value... but I am not understanding how to bind different value per instance...

For the below sample code, if you see, I would like to use same ColorClass implementation for all three colors Instances(named as "BLUE","RED","ORANGE") by passing different color as String variable.

```
public interface ColorInterface {
    public String getMeColor()
}
```

Sample implementation....

```
public class ColorClass implements ColorInterface {
    @Inject @Named("color")
    String color

    public String getMeColor(){
        return color
    } 

}
```

Sample binding........

```
public class ColorModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

             bind(ColorInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("BLUE")).to(ColorClass.class);
             bind(ColorInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("RED")).to(ColorClass.class);
             bind(ColorInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("ORANGE")).to(ColorClass.class);

            ......
    }

}
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 3):

If this directly is your issue, I would suggest a slight change in the implementation to move the injected `@Named("color") String` into a constructor argument and the use of a custom `Provider`:

```
public class ColorClass implements ColorInterface {
    String color;

    ColorClass(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getMeColor(){
        return color;
    }

    public static Provider implements Provider<ColorClass> {
        String color;
        public Provider(String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
        public ColorClass get() {
            return new ColorClass(color);
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your module:

```
public class ColorModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

             bind(ColorInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("BLUE"))
                 .toProvider(new ColorClass.Provider("Blue"));
             bind(ColorInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("RED"))
                 .toProvider(new ColorClass.Provider("Red"));
             bind(ColorInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("ORANGE"))
                 .toProvider(new ColorClass.Provider("Orange"));
    }

}
```

Obviously, the `Provider` doesn't need to be a static inner class like I did there, just something in the same package.

In case this exact problem isn't really your problem and you really do need `@Named("color") String` to be differently injected (say, you've actually got some really deep nested structure pulled together with guice and need a different binding deep in the hierarchy, and can't easily refactor that into a constructor parameter), then you'll need to use [private modules](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html).

However, that technique is **vast overkill** for the case you presented, so I'm hesitant to dive into it here. It's really a rather advanced topic you shouldn't try to tackle unless you really need to solve the problem it solves. (The problem is sometimes referred to as the "Robot Arms" problem)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This is the right solution to my problem

Comment: @rock if you like the solution, could you accept the answer?